# How can you sort by the lesser of two dates in Elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Scenario:
I have data that has two date fields (`created_at` and `published_on`). In some cases the dates are not right, and I need to sort by the lesser (older) of the two dates.

In other words, for each item, figure out the older date, and then use that to sort on.

I see from the documentation that you can sort by fields "sequentially" (eg: sort by name and then sort by city), and I see some numerical sort options (min/max, etc). But I'm struggling with how to achieve this.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994752/rails-order-sort-dates-based-on-two-different-dates) describes how this works in something like PostgreSQL but I know that Elastic is a completely different animal, so I'm hoping there's some way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract one value out of the two fields and then sort based on that value. For this you need [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting). In your query dsl you have to add the sort param as below:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "source": "if(doc['created_at'].value.getMillis() < doc['published_on'].value.getMillis()) { return doc['created_at'].value.getMillis(); } else { return doc['published_on'].value.getMillis(); }",
        "lang": "painless"
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```