# Trying Script based Sort on difference of two date fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have two fields createdAt and updatedAt, I want to sort the documents on difference of these

Comment: I think that answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54603006/18778181

Comment: HI @rabbitbr, This solution provided in the link worked for me.. Thanks for the help